# Targeting object within array JSON Steam API

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

How do I access `webm->max` in this [Steam API](http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=57690)? It's the order `[{` that confuses me, array of one before object? I'm not quite sure about the targeting here..

I've tried:

```
$gameTrailer = $game_json->57690->data->movies[0]->webm->max;
```

and

```
$gameTrailer = $game_json['57690']['data']['movies']['webm']['max'];
```

The API text is like this:

```
"movies": [{
    "id": 2029441,
    "name": "Tropico 4 Gameplay Trailer",
    "thumbnail": "http:\/\/cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com\/steam\/apps\/2029441\/movie.293x165.jpg?t=1447358847",
    "webm": {
        "480": "http:\/\/cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com\/steam\/apps\/2029441\/movie480.webm?t=1447358847",
        "max": "http:\/\/cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com\/steam\/apps\/2029441\/movie_max.webm?t=1447358847"
    },
    "highlight": true
}],
```

and "movies" lies within:

```
{"57690": {
        "data": {
```

Assume I'll always want the very first movie in an array (which in this case is an array of one). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax:

```
$game_json->{57690}->data->movies[0]->webm->max
```

When you have an object with a numeric key, you have to wrap the key name by curly brackets (Numeric keys are not valid property names).

If you use the associative option:

```
json_decode( $data, True );
```

your second attempt is almost right. Simply add the correct index after `movie`:

```
$gameTrailer = $game_json['57690']['data']['movies'][0]['webm']['max'];
```

Comment: Okay, but I get "Trying to get property of non-object in" on that particular line even with curly brackets..

Comment: Do you use `True` as second parameter while decoding JSON?

Comment: I just learned something new. Thank you! I figured myself that the `[0]` with `true` as 2nd parameter for decoding activated would count as another object, act like e.g. `['data']` if you catch my drift.